# iPod was stolen. Can I retrieve my Minecraft PE world?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

So my iPod was stolen while it had my favorite Minecraft pocket edition world. Can I get it back? It was not backed up. Any way I can retrieve it?

Answer (score 3):

If it wasn't backed up to iCloud then the only way is getting your iPod back.